# DBT macro on sql from path of delta table

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I'm trying to use the DBT macro ( which returns a latest partition from the delta table ) on sql from clause.

I see the path is not adding the partitions in the end. macro is actually printing the partitions as 1. That means its getting called, but somehow its not getting added in the path.

Is the syntax correct? I mean the way how i call the macro on the sql from clause?

Basically macro is not returning the output.

**code example:**

**sql model:**

```
select distinct
  col1,
  col2
from
{% if env_var('environment') == 'dev' %}
    delta.`{{ env_var('table1') }}`
{% else %}
    delta.`{{ env_var('table1') }}`{{ get_partitions() }}
{% endif %}
```

**Macro code:**

```
{% macro get_partitions() %}

    {% set latest_partitions_query %}
        select "1"
    {% endset %}

    {% if execute %}
    {% set latest_partitions_query_results = run_query(latest_partitions_query) %}

    {% if latest_partitions_query_results|length > 0 %}
        {{ log("Latest partitions: " ~ latest_partitions_query_results[0][0], True) }}
        {% set results = latest_partitions_query_results[0][0] %}
    {% else %}
        {{ log("No partitions returned by query.", True) }}
        {% set results = "" %}
    {% endif %}

    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

**UPDATE:**

Got it working by using return function.

```
return(results)
```

Comment: @tconbeer: could you check this please?

Comment: @tconbeer: got it working by using return, saw some of your other answers on stackoverflow and fixed it :)